# Считается ли запрос на загрузку самого (api-maps.yandex) как платный запрос?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Суть вопроса - когда мы делаем загрузку скрипта яндекс - карты считается ли это платным запросом?

Допустим я загружаю на одной странице через iframe карту несколько раз.
Это считается платным запросом?

Или же загрузка самого скрипта не считается.
https://monosnap.com/file/On00FjPGeFeNnWcjSwWzcZHzmFljS1 - пример загрузки.

У меня на странице как раз 3 вызова через iframe и моя цель - уменьшить количество платных запросов.

Что логичнее сделать в этом случае?
1. Подключить карту 1 раз и инициализировать при доскроле.
2. Инициализировать iframe с подгрузкой скриптов в каждом (предполагаю, что они не считаются - соответственно и не едят деньги, верно?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Подключение апи и создание карты не считается платным запросом.

> В API установлен лимит на общее число запросов к сервисам геокодирования, маршрутизации и панорам Яндекса. Запросы считаются суммарно по следующей формуле:
>
> число запросов в Геокодер + число запросов в Маршрутизатор + 5 × число запросов к Панорамам

[Условия использования API Яндекс.Карт - Лимиты запросов к API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/#index__limit-desc)

Но подгружать и инициализировать апи три раза на страницу может быть накладно для браузера.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Буду искать другие способы решения.